# TS Define a recursive type for an object where properties recursively have "parent" property

Tags: typescript, recursion

I'm trying to define a recursive type that takes in a type and produces a type where all the properties of the type recursively have a "parent" property, i.e., a reference to its parent object.

For instance, given this object:

```js
const originalValue = {
  person: {
    addresses: [
      {
        city: 'cincinnati',
      },
      {
        city: 'cincinnati',
        street: '123 street',
      },
    ],
    name: {
      first: 'david',
      aliases: [
        {
          last: 'dave',
        },
        {},
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Then `parentify` produces such an object like

```js
const value = parentify(originalValue);
expect(value.person.addresses[0].parent.parent.name.first).toEqual(originalValue.person.name.first);
```

Here's my type so far:

```
export type Parented<T, Parent = undefined> = T &
  (Parent extends undefined ? {} : { parent: Parent }) &
  (T extends any[]
    ? { [i in keyof T]: Parented<T[i], T> }
    : {
        [K in keyof T]: Parented<T[K], T>;
      });
```

[Here's a TS playground with a full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKBDKwB2NgAmAPACoA06Wu8AvHAK44HABmAljoQHxx0lwAyAFBw4ACkzY8cUPiYBnBk1YdCcAPxwA3gF84ALm1wwVPIcnU4OgJSCR4-rNwFFGHIgDaAXXujNWuA82OA44AGtgRAgWOBIvc1N8YhIgrwoSHh1fA21s0VEPAGkQnHDI6Nj4yikk0iK02K4AbjyraxahIVBIWDgAYwgceXgTGrYWRF44IgA1GRA5FzgAJWABqGJhqA4AcwpGMJwIAHccLi4xADcMABt6YEMZ2xoeLXsBoZHE4ChzKAgQIgABJuAg3H5ECAAIwAVmsYDw6G98nB5MAYIYWIw+jA2INxDAsDt0YY3IgKGB-mBSe4KNc7g84GTrIYoRAIOC3LkUaJxuIAIJQKAYRAAOjY8kFwsQV1u92stmRPNEH2G-QgYEQAHkWDM5ag6B5Rcb6fcvC1laIxANNTq9Qyma53NYPAByUbUV1eKaEqDEmAWy2qkZTTjHdD-QHWjXa3X6infKC2DBOzzm1qiMCiljQACiGD6AAsxLKGRQOMwQM8eGIwEFlCBvXRTcAFYHldgYPQoKUAIS9sS+-0eSkapvGdqtPTAG5okIxQfIYAVFu8Gh0V3QuE412KjPqz7GGmTOhhiMAmUBD1mBBE9FWBM1H6Ty1wHNQcTBsqTUItvevzMPAiRBxxbIDInTV8slfTtuz7Ach3REcqXHMAXx5adZ1QJUO3ROCCTvGBkLHKY-3bfJoIosh7B0QMv3+CAMSZdxQ2AcM0EjS8dEfahn0DBiYFFVdm31fi8J7OABKE-VHWqXjiBmZohFozoDzVaA2B2Dhbnte4phw-IUCgeRBkMAyUQwAgCGweQ0XkQwPH3URzKDNgkEMV0+g4LycBwDBcVdaiAIfJzuWC-o3MQDyfJ8vyAqC8KtmAEk4FdABGAAmABmVEYGwdFAtC7j9zSfc-IAW0ZFyUXYYymNdAgMEuNgCEK4LbjYFNgHswJQucvr8huFN6say5gDa8LivC7QpoA0qoISlFZtEFShC-YTjEScYZQ0rS-JuXTWw6AB6Y64AAYTcV14ChAswmOLAlmwFgflwPpUGveBEHRNbBjVeRCwgegbgIAAhYASCgPSRIZUUjJMnBRUs6zursjwAAYvDhxJsZqUUKuAbM2Dqtc6F27SDv1OGfgR-GMEqom6paL8AaBkH+VnCBwch6G4BbanjMGOmGdq4ZceocW8GFwnRdodc4HJ-bDoF2mCcZ4YmiAA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a small refactor.

Please try if it works for you

```js
type Helper<Parent> = Parent extends undefined ? {} : { parent: Parent }

export type Parented<T, Parent = undefined> = 
  & T 
  & Helper<Parent> 
  & { [K in keyof T]: Parented<T[K], T & Helper<Parent>> }
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally figured out a solution (but there may be a more elegant way to reduce the repetition):

```js
export type Parented<T, Parent = undefined> = T &
  (Parent extends undefined ? {} : { parent: Parent }) &
  (T extends any[]
    ? { [i in keyof T]: Parented<T[i], T & (Parent extends undefined ? {} : { parent: Parent })> }
    : {
        [K in keyof T]: Parented<T[K], T & (Parent extends undefined ? {} : { parent: Parent })>;
      });
```

[Resolved playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKBDKwB2NgAmAPACoA06Wu8AvHAK44HABmAljoQHxx0lwAyAFBw4ACkzY8cUPiYBnBk1YdCcAPxwA3gF84ALm1wwVPIcnU4OgJSCR4-rNwFFGHIgDaAXXujNWuA82OA44AGtgRAgWOBIvc1N8YhIgrwp+AXELaScFJWZ2TgINbT1DAJMpGASqq2seHV8DbSbRUQ8AaRCccMjo2PjKKsJSTrTYwSzEmRA5F3yVIpLdZorEmssbLgBuVrrdoSFQSFg4AGMIHHl4Suo2FkReOCIANRm5xQAlYAuoYmuoBwAOYURhhHAQADuOC4XDEADcMAAbejAQwvWw0HhaewXK43RLAKDmKAQECIAASbgISKJRAgACMAFY-GA8Og4tpweTAapwFiMM4wNiXcQwLBA3mGNyIChgUlgaXuCiIlFouAy6yGBkQCC0twtLmie7iACCUCgGEQADo2PJzZbEAjkajrLZOUbRHjrucIGBEAB5FgvF2oOgea2R1Wory7T2iMQXf1BkNqjWudzWDwAclueGzXie4qgkpgcfj3puT04kPQpPJib9geDoblhKgtgwGc8sb2ojA1pY0AAohgzgALMTOtUUDjMECYnhiMBBZQgQt0aPAN3lz3YGD0KA9ACEx7ExdLHnlfo3xmsu7aemASJ5IRi5+QwH6W94NDo2cZFkhWzd0+19fFjCVR46BrOsySdNYqkMC9eSsNthg7B8uSHKBxErXpHlCLdQPjNoVwiRBby3DwKN7UjGlI-dDxPM8UJgK8FVvMB7z2J8X1QD0915ZixQlXkOJvJ5iKwqwmh0Mh7B0ct8NJCA+RlatgFrNB6wQ+TjHbHjRFUmBrR-TdQ3LJijzgEyzNDdMhmoEYXh2IQlMOcCfWgNggQ4ZFU1RJ5BLIol5EucowIwAgCGweQeXkQwPDA0QQtIs42CQQxswynBcpwDBhWzBTSNEeSUsNUqvUyxBsty-LCrYYqKtEAFgClOBswARgAJgAZm5GBsF5ZqqvK0i0jAgqAFt1TSo12Cga5soIDB4TYAhRtK5E2C7YBEsCFrKqq0QkS7Pls1W+FgC2saSpO3R7omp6jXG16Xo8oR8PMgyqnuJ0fL8gqkUC7cDgAenBuAAFl6CRYUwFpOAGTHMJISweZsBYIlcDOfa4EhaAwjgJl6B9QpgC+y4fXkccIDhggACFgBIKAgostVrRQJbLmtaLYv2hKPAABi8LnEnFqprRm4BBzYJbaD-OBAf8kHQy5sLeZluWFd2fDafppECFNF8IGZ1n2bgLcNZ5nBpYwWadeuSXqBdvB7cdxafT-OgVeB0GbfCu3ta9ssgA)

Comment: Well, your two clauses with `i` and `K` are identical types, so you don't need to do that `T extends any[]` check at all.  If you're just trying to distribute over `T` you can do `T extends any ? {[K in ....} : never`

Comment: hence, no need to do `T extends any[]`